# Counting the number of times a specific database table entry is queried?

Tags: database, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to **keep track of the number of times each table entry is queried** so as to ascertain their popularity and eventually sort by that value.

If it makes it easier i am using symfony with the doctrine bundle.

All search so far only pertains to counts of records in table when searching hit count for table entry. Have not found any thing so far.

I have not tried this but what I am looking for is something **more efficient, fast and easier than changing my querying operations and calling another update query of each return result to increment the hit count**.

I expect each database table record to have number of times queried before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to count the number of accesses yourself, as PostgreSQL doesn't track such information.

You can add a `counter` column that is initialized to 0 and query like this:

```
UPDATE mytab
SET counter = counter + 1
WHERE ...
RETURNING *;
```

This is an atomic operation that won't suffer from race conditions. You could, however, experience deadlocks if you select more than one row at a time.

Since frequent updates are a killer for PostgreSQL, make sure that you get HOT updates:

- Create the table with a `fillfactor` significantly below 100, so that there is free space in each block.
- Don't put an index on `counter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v$sqlstats`.
So if you query is

```
select 10 from dual;
```

Then to count no of execution you can use below query

```
select executions 
  from v$sqlstats 
 where lower(sql_text) like 'select 10 from dual';
```

Comment: This is PostgreSQL, not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Just went with a counter field and incremented each time I queried.

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres **Statistics Collector** may be helpful to you. It isn't enable by default because of the overhead so to enable it you need to **edit postgres.conf** in /etc/postgresql//main

Search for "Statistics" and you should find the following section

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STATISTICS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Query and Index Statistics Collector -

#track_activities = on
#track_activity_query_size = 1024   # (change requires restart)
#track_counts = on
#track_io_timing = off
#track_wal_io_timing = off
#track_functions = none         # none, pl, all
#stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/14-main.pg_stat_tmp'
```

un-comment this section and then run `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`

You can then run the following to view the various stats in addition to other functions outlined by the Statistics Collector docs

```
SELECT * from pg_stat_user_tables;
```

Documentation for changes required in postgres.conf: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-statistics.html

Documentation for using Statistics Collector: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/monitoring-stats.html